# Why does Mathematica give no output?

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, nonlinear

I am trying to solve a system of coupled differential equations. I am using the following code:

```
DSolve[
    {D[A[z], z] + B[z]*(Λ - Sqrt[2]*b) - (a/Sqrt[2])*(A[z]^2 - B[z]^2)*B[z] == 0, 
     D[B[z], z] - A[z]*(Λ + Sqrt[2]*b) - (a/Sqrt[2])*(A[z]^2 - B[z]^2)*A[z] == 0}, 
{A[z], B[z]}, z]
```

Upon executing, Mathematica gives no output at all. It does not even give an error message. What's wrong?

Comment: Mathematica 11.2 returns unevaluated, probably because it cannot solve this problem.  Many nonlinear ODEs have no solution.

Comment: putting assumptions on your parameters (real, positive) might help, but not likely

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because this system of ODEs is autonomous, `z` can be eliminated, reducing the system to a single first order ODE.

```
eq1 = D[A[z], z] == -B[z]*(Λ - Sqrt[2]*b) + (a/Sqrt[2])*(A[z]^2 - B[z]^2)*B[z];
eq2 = D[B[z], z] == +A[z]*(Λ + Sqrt[2]*b) + (a/Sqrt[2])*(A[z]^2 - B[z]^2)*A[z];
```

Specifically, replace `A[z]` by `x` and `B[z]` by `y[x]`:

```
eq = eq2 /. B'[z] -> y'[x] A'[z] /. A'[z] -> eq1[[2]] /. {B[z] -> y[x], A[z] -> x}

(* (-(-Sqrt[2] b + Λ) y[x] + (a y[x] (x^2 - y[x]^2))/Sqrt[2]) y'[x] == 
       x (Sqrt[2] b + Λ) + (a x (x^2 - y[x]^2))/Sqrt[2] *)
```

from which `DSolve` obtains a parametric solution.

```
sol = Values@DSolve[eq, y[x], x] // Flatten

{-Sqrt[(2 b)/a + x^2 - (Sqrt[2] Λ)/a - (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[2 b^2 - 2 Sqrt[2] b Λ - 
       2 Sqrt[2] a x^2 Λ + Λ^2 + Sqrt[2] a C[1]])/a], 
  Sqrt[(2 b)/a + x^2 - (Sqrt[2] Λ)/a - (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[2 b^2 - 2 Sqrt[2] b Λ - 
       2 Sqrt[2] a x^2 Λ + Λ^2 + Sqrt[2] a C[1]])/a], 
 -Sqrt[(2 b)/a + x^2 - (Sqrt[2] Λ)/a + (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[2 b^2 - 2 Sqrt[2] b Λ - 
       2 Sqrt[2] a x^2 Λ + Λ^2 + Sqrt[2] a C[1]])/a], 
  Sqrt[(2 b)/a + x^2 - (Sqrt[2] Λ)/a + (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[2 b^2 - 2 Sqrt[2] b Λ - 
       2 Sqrt[2] a x^2 Λ + Λ^2 + Sqrt[2] a C[1]])/a]}
```

Here is a sample plot

```
Plot[sol /. {Λ -> 1, a -> 1, b -> 1} /. C[1] -> 2, {x, -1.1, 1.1}, AxesLabel -> {A, B}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, Medium], AspectRatio -> Full]
```

[image]

This result can be validated by direct numerical solution of the original equations.

```
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq1, eq2, A[0] == A0, B[0] == B0}, {A, B}, {z, 0, 10}, 
    {A0, B0, a, b, Λ}];

params = Sequence[1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
Plot[Evaluate@Through[s[params][z]], {z, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {z, "A, B"}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, Medium]]
ParametricPlot[Evaluate@Through[s[params][z]], {z, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {A, B}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, Medium], AspectRatio -> Full]
```

[image]

and a parametric plot identical to the first plot in this answer.

**Addendum**

Given that `sol` provides `B` as a function of `A`, in principle `A` can be determined as a function of `z` from

```
Simplify[eq1 /. B[z] -> sol[[j]] /. x -> A[z]]
```

where `j` represents each of the four components of `sol`.  For instance, with `j == 1`,

```
(* Sqrt[2 b^2 - 2 Sqrt[2] b Λ + Λ^2 - 2 Sqrt[2] a Λ A[z]^2 + Sqrt[2] a C[1]] 
   Sqrt[(2 b + a A[z]^2 - Sqrt[2] (Λ + Sqrt[2 b^2 - 2 Sqrt[2] b Λ + Λ^2 - 
   2 Sqrt[2] a Λ A[z]^2 + Sqrt[2] a C[1]]))/a] + A'[z] == 0 *)
```

which can be solved with `DSolveValue` or `Integrate`.  Unfortunately, neither gives a closed-form solution for `A[z]`.  In summary, this answer derives a parametric relation between `A` and `B`, but does not provide closed-form solutions for `A` or `B` as functions of `z`.  Whether the parametric solution is sufficient depends on the OP's goal.